# Core Plot Charts Axis Position

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-plot

I'm using core plot 1.0. Currently I'm making the X axis draw say 20 points above the bottom of the screen (so the labels can show up) by defining the Y range a little bit below 0.

Now I was asked that the origin point should be 0.0 and there should not be anything below 0 in both axes, so I'm now looking at the core plot documentation and scratching my head with the following question:

What property do I need to set to move the axes at the position I'd like to and also keep on showing the point labels and axis titles?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found it so I leave it here for if somebody else needs help with this.

It is kind of tricky, you need to adjust the `xRange` and `yRange` on the plot space so it's big enough to draw the labels, the ticks and the titles and then adjust the `visibleRange` property on each axis. At this point you get the amount of axis you want and still displaying the information you need.

If someone knows a better way please share :)